# How to construct array of objects inside $.each(?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

My current code pushes the key into normal array but i want to push both key and value in to array of object. I appreciate if an expert show me how this can be done.Thanks

Javascript to create the object array:

```
var xml ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <dict><key>ItemLists</key> <array><dict><key>id</key> <string>1</string> <key>name</key> <string>fruits</string> <key>category</key> <string>US Fruits</string> <key>categoryIcon</key> <string>http://www.somsite.com/categories/1.jpg</string> <key>country</key> <string>US</string> </dict> <dict><key>id</key> <string>2</string> <key>name</key> <string>Vegetable</string> <key>category</key> <string>Eu Vegetable</string> <key>categoryIcon</key> <string>http://www.somsite.com/categories/2.jpg</string> <key>country</key> <string>EU</string> </dict> </array> </dict>';

        xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
        $xml = $(xmlDoc);

var MyArray=[];
$(xml).find("array key").each(function(){
    var key = $(this).text();
    var value = $(this).next().text();  
    console.log(key + "=" + value);
    //here  i want to create array of objects instead of normal array
    //and push both key and value to array of object
    MyArray.push(key);
});
```

Object array sample that i want construct:

```
var myArray = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'fruits',
    category: 'US Fruits',
    categoryIcon: 'http://www.somsite.com/categories/1.jpg',
    country: 'US'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Vegetable',
    category: 'Eu Vegetable',
    categoryIcon: 'http://www.somsite.com/categories/2.jpg',
    country: 'EU'
}, ];
```

edit:
I tried to print the array of objects like this but i got undefined for all
values!:

```
$.each(MyArray,function(j, object){

var div = "<tr id=\""+j+"\">\n" +
    "<td>"+j+"</td>\n" +
    "<td><img src=\""+ object.categoryIcon +"\" height=\"42\" width=\"42\"></td>\n" +
    "<td>\n" +
    "<a href=\"javascript:doit('id=" + object.id + "&name=" + object.name + "&category=" + object.category + "&categoryIcon=" + object.categoryIcon + "','"+ object.country +"')\" onclick=\"selectLink(this);\">" + object.name + "</a><br> \n" +
    "<br></td></tr>\n\n";
 $("#myDiv").append(div);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are collecting different objects, you should in fact have two loops: one for collecting the object properties for one dict, and one for collecting those objects into an array:

```
var myArray=[];
$(xml).find("array dict").each(function(){
    var obj = {};
    $(this).find("key").each(function () {
        var key = $(this).text();
        var value = $(this).next().text();  
        console.log(key + "=" + value);
        obj[key] = value;
    });
    myArray.push(obj);
});
```

With ES6 you can shorten this to the following code:

```
var myArray = $(xmlDoc).find("array dict").get().map( dict =>
    $(dict).find("key").get().reduce( (obj, el) =>
        Object.assign(obj, { [$(el).text()]: $(el).next().text() }), {}));
```

```js
var xml ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <dict><key>ItemLists</key> <array><dict><key>id</key> <string>1</string> <key>name</key> <string>fruits</string> <key>category</key> <string>US Fruits</string> <key>categoryIcon</key> <string>http://www.somsite.com/categories/1.jpg</string> <key>country</key> <string>US</string> </dict> <dict><key>id</key> <string>2</string> <key>name</key> <string>Vegetable</string> <key>category</key> <string>Eu Vegetable</string> <key>categoryIcon</key> <string>http://www.somsite.com/categories/2.jpg</string> <key>country</key> <string>EU</string> </dict> </array> </dict>';

var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);

var myArray = $(xmlDoc).find("array dict").get().map( dict =>
    $(dict).find("key").get().reduce( (obj, el) =>
        Object.assign(obj, { [$(el).text()]: $(el).next().text() }), {}));

console.log(myArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: many thanks .your code worked like a charm. I didn't know that we need two loops.

Answer (score 5):

If you just replace

```
MyArray.push(key);
```

with

```
var o = {};
o[key] = value;

MyArray.push(o);
```

It would do that, but you seem to want to iterate over each `dict`, and then get the value of each `key` inside the parent `dict` etc.

```js
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <dict><key>ItemLists</key> <array><dict><key>id</key> <string>1</string> <key>name</key> <string>fruits</string> <key>category</key> <string>US Fruits</string> <key>categoryIcon</key> <string>http://www.somsite.com/categories/1.jpg</string> <key>country</key> <string>US</string> </dict> <dict><key>id</key> <string>2</string> <key>name</key> <string>Vegetable</string> <key>category</key> <string>Eu Vegetable</string> <key>categoryIcon</key> <string>http://www.somsite.com/categories/2.jpg</string> <key>country</key> <string>EU</string> </dict> </array> </dict>';

var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
    $xml = $(xmlDoc);

var MyArray = [];
$(xml).find("array dict").each(function(_,elem) {
 var o = {};
 $('key', elem).each(function() {
        var key = $(this).text();
        var value = $(this).next().text();
        o[key] = value;
    });
    MyArray.push(o);
});
console.log(MyArray)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {top:0; min-height:100%!important}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Alternativetely, you could use `map()` and `reduce()`

```
var MyArray = $(xml).find("array dict").map(function(_,elem) {
    return $('key', elem).toArray().reduce(function(a,b) {
        return a[$(b).text()] = $(b).next().text(), a;
    }, {});
}).get();
```

Comment: Thanks for replies. @adeneo i tried to use your first suggestion but now when i try to print the array of object i get all undefined for variables!(see my first post edit part). It seems the array didn't push the data correctly! could you tell me how to fix it ?